# Temporary and Permanent Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am creating Stored Procedure in Oracle and one of them is created permanently and another one is temporarily created and vanished after serving its purpose.How it is working please give your guidance when to use and how it is created.

---- This is not created in DB, just temporarily created and vanished

```
DECLARE   name varchar2(10);
PROCEDURE printVal (name varchar2) IS
BEGIN
   dbms_output.put_line ('name:' || name);
END;  
BEGIN
  name := 'Joe';
  printVal(name);
END;
/
```

---- This is created in DB and permanently available

```
create PROCEDURE printVal (name varchar2) IS
BEGIN
   dbms_output.put_line ('name:' || name);
END;
```

Comment: I think you're confused because the first anonymous block contains a pl/sql [subprogram](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/subprograms.htm#LNPLS008) , which defines a name (printVal).  But because it exists inside an anonymous block, it isn't stored in the db.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies and answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand, Dividing your sql in two parts.

**Stored Procedure:**

- Stored procedures are stored in database.
- We can call stored procedures any time after creation.
- Stored procedures also supports input output parameters.

**Anonymous Block:**

- These are unnamed pl/sql blocks.
- Anonymous blocks are not stored in database.
- Cannot pass paramters

---

```
---------- Stored Procedure Start--------

DECLARE   name varchar2(10);
PROCEDURE printVal (name varchar2) IS
BEGIN
   dbms_output.put_line ('name:' || name);
END;  
--------- Stored Procedure End-----------

----------anonymous block Start----------
BEGIN
  name := 'Joe';
  printVal(name);
END;
/
----------anonymous block end ------------
```

Comment: what you mean by Cannot pass paramters ? here in my first example we pass value to SP temporarily create.

Comment: "Cannot pass parameters" - i mean just we can not define input output parameters in anonymous block like we define in a stored procedure.

Comment: The procedure in the example is not stored, so it's not a stored procedure. Also might be worth mentioning that the `/` character is only required by some client tools for indicating the end of input and an instruction to execute, rather than part of the PL/SQL language.

Answer (score 3):

Well, clearly there is different syntax -- the first one is an anonymous block, and the second creates a stored procedure. The expected behaviour is exactly what you observe, and covered by Oracle PL/SQL documentation. https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/overview.htm#LNPLS141